# DateTimeFormatter.withLocale(): reference of all the patterns depending on FormatStyle and Locale

Tags: java, design-patterns, time, format, locale

I'm trying to find which norm/specification - if any - references all the patterns available in Java (using Java 8 or joda dateTimeFormatter), depending on Locale and FormatStyle?

In other words, if I could run the [patternForStyle](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#patternForStyle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)) method on any Locale / Style, what result should I expect?

Did any international standardization body (ISO, IEC, IETF..) describe this?.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You're asking for off-site resources, which is not what this site is geared towards.  Please make sure you ask questions that are on-topic - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: By the way, the only comprehensive standard for date-time formats I know of is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). These standard formats are used by default in the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes when parsing/generating strings. But these are designed to facilitate data exchange, not localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 is following [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/tools), so [their website](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time-patterns) may be the place to check.

I couldn't find a link with the specific info you want, though. Probably the best way is to check using Java 8 itself:

```
for (FormatStyle fs : FormatStyle.values()) {
    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        // get pattern for locale and style
        String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(fs, fs, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not one authoritative source for localized date-time formatting patterns.

You may have a look at a couple of Wikipedia articles

- [Date format by country](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)
- [Date and time notation in Europe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe)

Also note that there are links from each article. I find them informative, but by no means authoritative. I have not checked to see what extend Java follows the information given.

Since localized patterns are exactly localized, they fall outside what international standard organizations (like ISO) corcern themselves with. Some national and probably regional/local organizations try to set standards for their own country or region.